# Office 2016 HTML email anchor tags are not working/clickable

Tags: html-email, windows-10, office-2016

After upgrading to Windows 10 and Office 2016.. In HTML Email anchor tags are not clickable.. which are working fine in office 2013. Did anybody face this issue? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bug in Office 2016, we reported this in support.